How to generate output while iterating with Del?
I'm knocking off 30+ years of rust and poking at APL again.  I was working through some Project Euler questions and ran into an interesting problem.  I defined the following function to evaluate "primeness":
prime←{0=+/0=⍵|⍨1↓⍳⌊⍵÷2}

This works fine for all reasonable cases, though it's clearly not the most efficient approach.  However, the problem arises when I embed it in this conditional:
{⍺←6⋄prime ⍵ : (⍺+1)∇(⍵+1),⎕←⍺,⍵ ⋄ ⍺∇(⍵+1)}12

This works fine for the non-prime case, but creates an issue for primes since I'm now creating something that is the wrong shape by trying to generate output while performing the recursion with the ,⎕←⍺,⍵ clause.
The intention is the output which prime has been found and the value of the prime.  I'm starting with ⍺←6 and ⍵←12 so the 6th prime, 13, is correctly found first.
Is there a way to use quad (or something) to generate some output while recursing?

As an alternative to chaining with ⊣ per LdBeth's answer, you can invert your condition, allowing multiple statements in the "else":
{⍺←6 ⋄ ~prime ⍵ : ⍺∇(⍵+1) ⋄ ⎕←⍺,⍵ ⋄ (⍺+1)∇(⍵+1)}12

Attempt this online!

Ahhhh... that's what I was hunting for.  Thank you.  It effectively leads to two actions for a false condition. Thank you!

I guess you want ⊣ instead of ,. Also note that your recursive definition does not have a terminate condition so it will run forever until manual interrupt.
      {⍺←6 ⋄ ∨/prime⍤0⊢⍵:(⍺+1)∇(⍵+1)⊣⎕←⍺,⍵ ⋄ ⍺ ∇(⍵+1)}12
6 13
7 17
8 19
9 23
10 29
11 31
12 37
13 41
14 43
15 47
16 53
17 59
18 61
19 67
...


Why did you change prime ⍵ into prime⍤0⊢⍵?

@Adám because the , before quad is very confusing and the problem description is not clear on that, especially lacking a proper termination condition and expected output makes me wonder. And if the concatenation is intentional, rank operator needs to be there for prime function working on an array

Yes, I didn't mind the infinite run. Yes, the , is not the right thing to do but I couldn't come up with how to do two things at once..
